# get modified file before it is saved in RAD Studio

Tags: c++, delphi, command-line

I want to use the command line compiler to compile my project.
Currently i use the following command, i excecute this command with the RAD Studio command line.

```
msbuild MyProject.dproj /t:Build /p:config=Release
```

instructions on how to use this can be found here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command

This works fine, only i have one problem.
I want to do this while i am editing my code in RAD Studio, but if i don't save my file, the unmodified version is used by the command line compiler.
i don't want to safe the file everytime i want to compile.

Is there a way to let the compiler use the modified file, without forcing me to save the file?

Comment: You will have to save it somehow. The command line compiler can not access the contents of the editor in the IDE. In other words: **no, you can't do that without saving**.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis i was afraid for that, i hoped somebody else knew more than me. Thank you anyway

Comment: Why are you afraid of saving?  If you don't use version control, this is a perfect time to start.

Comment: The command line compiler uses files that are on disk. It has no knowledge of content that hasn't been saved to the file, because *that content has not yet been saved to the file*. Common sense applies here. The command line compiler doesn't have any knowledge about whether the IDE is open or  not, and can't access memory unrelated to the file in order to see if that memory content might apply to the file. The IDE reads the content of the file when you open it, and then closes the file. It doesn't keep it open or lock it in any way the command line compiler would be able to detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way. The compiler compiles the file on disk, and unless you save your work, the IDE won't update the file on disk.

The only reason I can think of that you might wish not to save your work is if you think you'll want to close your file without keeping your most recent changes because the changes proved not to work. There are two reasons you don't need to worry about that. First is that Delphi allows you to undo you changes even after you save them. Second is that you can revert your changes through your source-control system.

Comment: I want to use this in a plug-in i am currently working on. The problem here is that i don't want to force the user to save their file.

Comment: As a plug-in, you'd have access to the IDE's buffer. You could save the buffer contents to a temporary file and compile that instead. No idea how that would interact with the rest of the project that uses that unit, though.

Comment: that's a possibility that came to my mind, but i'm afraid i have to copy the whole project. safe the files there, and compile. But with large projects, that might cause some performance issues.

Comment: @reinierstam This is just curiosity, but what are you trying to solve with a temporary/throwaway compile like this?

Comment: That the latest edits of the user is also automaticly reviewd